# TeamCity FxCop runner: Specifying assemblies

Tags: teamcity, fxcop

My first thought is that is would be bad practice to list each dll individually. I want to avoid having to edit my TC configuration every time someone creates a new project/dll.

Although with the traditional directory structure I can't find any sensible wildcard pattern.

**Directory structure**

- Solution

  - Container

    - bin

      - Debug
  - Core

    - bin

      - Debug
  - Web

    - bin

      - Debug
  - ...

Any wildcard pattern (like `**\bin\**.dll`) will match the same DLLs multiple times.

How do you guys specify what assemblies to inspect with FxCop in TeamCity?

Comment: Is your goal to fail the build on any unsuppressed rule violation or just to produce a report?

Answer (score 3):

I have a unit test project that references all the other projects in my solution. The DLL's generated by the other projects are copied locally when the unit test project is built, so I run all my analysis on that single bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

The most comfortable way for me is a FxCop project file checked in repository. So I have the same report on developer machine and on build server.

Comment: I'm assuming you have to edit the FxCop project file each time you add a new project to your solution?